# Laravel error: Query not returning certain columns from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with 5 columns and when I query select all columns, 1 column is ignored.

My table columns: `id` `setting_key` `created_at` `updated_at` `app_setting`

My query looks like this:

```
$result = DB::connection($token)->table('settings')->select('*')->get();
```

The missing column is `app_setting` and this exact same query is used in another part of my code and returns all 5 columns including `app_setting`.

If I add an addSelect to the query as so:

```
$query = DB::connection($token)->table('settings')->select('*');
$result = $query->addSelect('app_setting')->get();
```

I get an error 'Column not found: 1054' even though the column most definitely exists. Why would I be getting this error if the column exists and why does my original query not return all of the columns as it does in other areas of my code?

Edit: When I directly query the `app_setting` column, I get the values returned, but still get 'Column not found'. How is that possible?

Comment: Could you please include your table columns in the desription? Thank you

Comment: @ErrBon Updated!

Answer (score 0):

first check your .env, that DB_database and DB_username and DB_password are correct or not. use the code below in the controller then run that function and post the result here

```
$result = DB::table('settings')->where('id',1)->first();
dd($result->app_setting);
```

before running the query fill a dummy data in the database.

Comment: When I run this query, I get the value for app_setting which is 0 for id = 1. However I'm still getting a laravel log error that app_setting is undefined even though the field is there in my database. I'm not sure how that's possible.
Edit: My .env is all correct

Comment: why are you using connection, only use  DB::table('setting')->get();

Comment: I am connecting to different remote dbs based on a specific client token. Either way this shouldn't be happening. I use the same function in another part of my code, same query and all and it returns all data fields. However here it does not